# Converting a character to an 3 digit integer in C

Tags: c

The input is be stored in a char and whatever the input is like even 3 digit integer it should be outputed to the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char a;

printf("Enter a character  :");
a=getche();

int x = (int)a - 48;

printf("\n Character is %d",x);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getche` is no standard function.

Comment: Yes it is. It gets a character. But i want to get char and the char is for example  "123" . I want the console show same "123"

Comment: Have you tried using getc or getchar?

Comment: @MajkJohnoson No your mistaken. `getche()` is not standard I believe its found in the `conio.h` header if im not mistaken. Use either `getchar()` or `getc(FILE *stream)`

Comment: Yes it gets now a character  but when i enter for example 352 it shows to the console just 3. This is the main problem.

Comment: @MajkJohnoson Because you cant store 352 in a `char` a `char` can hold one character 352 is three characters... Is this what you mean

Comment: Converting "a character" instead of characters to three-digit integer? Do you mean something like this? `char c = 'y'; printf("%d\n", c);` (for ASCII code)

Comment: "123" is a string, not a character. You should consult a C book to read a character-sequence from console or simply user-input, e.g. with `scanf`. And don't use proprietary functions where a standard one works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive implementation without error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {

    int a, b, c;

    printf("Enter three characters :");
    a=getchar();
    b=getchar();
    c=getchar();

    int x = (a - '0') * 100 + (b - '0') * 10 + (c - '0');

    printf("\n Characters are %03d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that

- Not knowing about `getche()`, `getchar()` will return `int`, and it may return `EOF`, whuch won't fit in `char`. Therefore, using `int` to store what `getchar()` returns is a good idea.
- You should use `'0'` instead of `48` for portability. It is guaranteed in ANSI C that `'1' - '0' == 1`, ... , `'9' - '0' == 9` in C.

Comment: Thank you Mike , this was what i was asking.

Comment: Last question, can this putted in a loop , to ask many times  enter a 3 digit number till  pressing something special ?

Comment: Sorry, this code is too naive and not suitable for looping. Please consider using `scanf()`.